# Are topological spaces $X,Y$ homeomorphic if each is homeomorphic to a subspace of the other?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

The Schroeder-Bernstein theorem states that

> If $A$ and $B$ are two sets and there exists injective maps $f:A \to B$ and $g:B \to A$, then there exists a bijection $h:A \to B$.

The statement above is equivalent to the following

> Suppose $A_1 \subset A$ and $B_1 \subset B$ are sets such that there exists a bijective map $f:A \to B_1$ and $g:B \to A_1$, then there exists a bijection $h:A \to B$.

So I was thinking about the problem below. I couldn't prove it, but not getting a counterexample either. Any hints will be appreciated.

> Now suppose $A \subset X$, $B \subset Y$ are topological spaces, and suppose that there exists a homeomorphism $\alpha:A \to Y$ and $\beta: B \to X$, then can we conclude that $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic?

Comment: Related: [this math.overflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1058/when-does-cantor-bernstein-hold) and links therein.

Answer (score 6):

The topological version of Schroeder-Bernstein **fails badly**. For example, consider $(0,1)$ and $[0,1]$ with their usual topologies, which are of course non-homeomorphic:

- $(0,1)$ is homeomorphic to itself, which is a subspace of $[0,1]$.
- $[0,1]$ is homeomorphic to $[{1\over 3}, {1\over 2}]$, which is a subspace of $(0,1)$.

In general, the question of when Schroeder-Bernstein holds for a given category of mathematical objects is a quite interesting one; see e.g. [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1058/when-does-cantor-bernstein-hold). For example, while the counterexample above shows that Schroeder-Bernstein fails for metric spaces, it in fact *holds* for [compact metric spaces](https://mathoverflow.net/a/73332/8133) (and while $[0,1]$ is compact, $(0,1)$ isn't).

Comment: So you mean that this generalization will hold when $A,X,B$ and $Y$ are compact?

Comment: @zero2infinity Well, and we shift attention to *metric* spaces. Not all compact spaces are metrizable, after all, and homeomorphic metric spaces need not be isometric. But with those modifications, yes.

Answer (score 4):

No, Suppose $A=[-1,1], X=\mathbb{R}, B=(-2,2)$ and $Y=[-3,3]$. Then this gives a counter example

Answer (score 3):

No, consider $X = [0,1]$ and $Y = [0,1] \cup [2,3]$, with their usual subspace topologies. You may let $A = [0,1/3] \cup [1/3,2/3]$ and $B = [0,1]$. $X$ is connected while $Y$ is not.

Answer (score 2):

For example, consider $X=[0,1]$ and $Y=(0,1)$. $X$ is not homeomorphic to $Y.$ but $X$ is homeomorphic to $[1/4,3/4] \subset Y=(0,1).$ and Y is homeomorphic to $(0,1)\subset X.$